# No tag "connect" defined in tag library imported with prefix "c"

Tags: java, jsp

There's a couple of questions regarding this but there seems to have no fix yet. I'm trying to create a custom tag to display the current date. Here's my code.

This is my connect.tag file.

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="easy" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
    <%@ tag import="java.util.Date" 
        import="java.text.DateFormat"%>
    <% 
       DateFormat dateFormat = 
       DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
       Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
       out.println(dateFormat.format(now));
     %>
```

And here is my jsp file where I want to access my tag file.

```
     <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
     <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
```

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c"  tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

Today is <c:connect/>.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, anyone help me please?

Comment: try this tag <%@include file="tags.jsp" %>

Comment: where will i put this? in my tag file?

Answer (score 0):

You've create a custom tag and you try to access it via the core library. You called the core and your library with prefix "c"

I see this line in your connect.tag

```
<%@ taglib prefix="easy" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
```

so you are using a custom library of tags. You just have to use it in your jsp too if your connect.tag is in the directory `/WEB-INF/tags`

your jsp

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/" prefix="easy" %>
Today is <easy:connect/>.
```